# C# FrameWork 4 64 Bit Service InstalUtil Problem

Tags: windows-services, c#-4.0, installation

Platform WinServer 2008 R2

32 Bit Version of Service. 32 bit Instalutil  works OK

Took service and components upto Framework 4 and 64 bit.

64 bit InstalUtil complains Could not load file 'Path' An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format ..

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide/expand your question? It's a bit confusing currently

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've compiled your application as "x86" instead of "x64" (or "Any CPU"). On the project properties, under the "Build" tab, check that "Platform target" is set to "Any CPU" or "x64".

Visual Studio 2010, [by default](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=455333&wa=wsignin1.0), sets the target to x86.